# How Can I Set Up a Dual Boot with Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows 8.1 on Two SSDs in RAID0

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

So I am a complete novice when it comes to all things Linux/Ubuntu, but I have been trying to remedy that by making it so that my computer can boot either Ubuntu 15.04 or Windows 8.1, which came pre-installed on my laptop. I have an MSI GS70, which put the Windows OS on a pair of 128 GB SSDs which are arranged in RAID0. I have followed nearly every comprehensive guide I can find, but I can never seem to find the right partition to install Ubuntu on. I have no option to just "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows," and in the "Something Else" section I can't find the partition I created for Ubuntu. I think the problem is stemming from the fact that the drives are in RAID0, but I don't really know. I have read other forums where people explain some way of solving this, but, as I said before, I am completely new to this and their solutions went way over my head. If anyone has a solution that they can clearly explain or walk me through or even some helpful tips I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Are they in software or hardware RAID?  That is, do they show up as a single drive in the Ubuntu installer?

Comment: I believe they show up as two separate drives.

Comment: OK, so it looks like you've got software RAID inside windows.  this could get very very messy.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you use RAID?

Comment: For more speed?

Comment: Because my laptop came like that...honestly it was the one feature I didn't like, but since that was only one issue I still got it.

Comment: RAID0 isn't really very helpful.  You might be better off doing what I will suggest in a long detailed answer momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this will get ugly, but bear with me:

1. BACKUP BACKUP BACKUP Windows completely
2. Go to Control Panel --> System and find your Windows 8.1 product key
3. If you don't already have an install disk, go to microsoft's website (google is helpful here) and download an install image for windows 8.1, and burn it to a DVD or USB drive
4. Reinstall Windows 8.1, and delete all partitions on the drive during the install.  Also make sure to NOT use RAID0.  It is probably wise to install Windows on only 1 disk.  Just pick one and select to install to it.
5. Boot into the fresh copy of Windows 8.1 and restore from backups.
6. Boot from the Ubuntu install disk and select to install alongside Windows.
7. When that's done, your laptop should boot to a Greyish screen that gives you the option to boot either into Ubuntu or Windows.
8. Wipe the sweat off your brow.

Comment: Well, that sounds like it will work based on my limited knowledge of these things. I will start working on that later this evening when I have more time. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem.  Have your camera on hand and take pictures of anything suspicious.

Comment: AND MAKE SURE YOU BACKUP EVERYTHING!

Comment: If you don't, you'll never get it back.  Put it on an external hard drive and lock it in your safe until it's done.

Comment: I didn't get the chance to start this tonight, so before I get started is there any specific program you recommend for backing all of my stuff up? Just copy all the files I can onto an external hard drive, or should I create a recovery image?

Comment: Windows 7 included a file backup tool, so 8.1 should include that as well.  You could look for an option to migrate to a new computer using an external hard drive, and if there is one, that's going to be the easiest.

Comment: But copying files will work, you'll just have to put them back manually, as well as reconfigure any settings, reinstall drivers, etc.

Comment: Took a while to go through the whole process and I had some trouble reinstalling my drivers, but all in all it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem!  Anytime!